# FlyoutNavigation won't work with UIViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, navigation-drawer

So I have a major problem. When I use FlyoutNavigation to be my navigation drawer, I can't get it to animate unless I'm using a UITableView. As soon as I put a UITableView it animates

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so my problem was that the background wasn't loaded. As soon as I loaded a background... the problems went away.